# E1550 gsm modem does not switch to modem mode on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

My GSM modem E1550 does not switch to modem mode on connect.

`lsusb` :

```
...
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
...
```

`/var/log/usb_modeswitch.log` :

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Sun May 24 18:39:27 2015

Use global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf


Started via upstart
Raw args from udev: /3-6.2.4

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (3-6.2.4) ...
Use top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6.2.4

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6.2.4
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6.2.4
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
Check class of first interface ...
 Device is in install mode.
Use interface (null)
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor  12d1
  idProduct 1446
  manufacturer  HUAWEI Technology
  product   HUAWEI Mobile
  serial    (null)
  bNumConfigurations    1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1446*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1446*
SCSI attributes not needed, move on.

Extract config 12d1:1446 from collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProduct set to 1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1432,1433,1436,14ac,1506,150c,1511
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
! matched, now switching
Command to be run:
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -W -D -s 20 -c /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg -u -1   -v 12d1 -p 1446 2>&1

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are expected in the process)
--------------------------------

Read config file: /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg

 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.1.1 (C) Josua Dietze 2014
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1432,1433,1436,14ac,1506,150c,1511"
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000101000100000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled

Look for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 008 on bus 003
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01

Check for mode switch (max. 20 times, once per second) ...
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Search for target devices ...
  found USB ID 8087:8000
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 8087:8008
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 046d:c52b
  found USB ID 12d1:1446
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 09da:0260
  found USB ID 1a40:0101
  found USB ID 046d:0825
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0a12:0001
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No new devices in target mode or class found

Mode switch has failed. Bye!

fail:
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6.2.4
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

All done, exit
```

`dmesg` :

```
[   90.041227] usb 3-6.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   90.070302] usb 3-6.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1446
[   90.070305] usb 3-6.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   90.070307] usb 3-6.2.4: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[   90.070308] usb 3-6.2.4: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
[   90.095273] usb-storage 3-6.2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   90.095342] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-6.2.4:1.0
[   90.095395] usb-storage 3-6.2.4:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   90.095639] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-6.2.4:1.1
[   90.095683] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   91.096758] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   91.098823] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   91.109386] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[   91.109400] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[   91.109539] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[   91.109592] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[   91.109769] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   91.120814] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   91.121317] systemd-udevd[5848]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr0: No such file or directory
[   91.121323] systemd-udevd[5848]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr0: No such file or directory
[   91.131318] systemd-udevd[5822]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr0: No such file or directory
[   91.131324] systemd-udevd[5822]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr0: No such file or directory
```

I have found a way to switch it manually using the following command:
`usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1446 -s 5 -M 55534243000000000000000000000011060000000000000000000000000000`, but it behaves somehow unstable - sometimes it switches back to CD-ROM mode after 5-10 minutes.

Also I tried to add the following lines to `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`:

```
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
MessageContent="55534243000000000000000000000011060000000000000000000000000000"
MessageEndpoint=0x01
CheckSuccess=5
```

GSM modem switches on OS startup w/o problems but after suspend/resume it switches back to CD-ROM mode...

I want `usb_modeswitch` to work out of the box and as I know it must work in such way. I have found the following post on ubuntu forum: [Huaawei E398 not usable with Ubuntu 14.04LTS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219568) and that problem looks like mine and repeats only on Ubuntu 14.04 but it's not solved.